# JSF 1.2 - Does PostConstruct execute before or after getters

Tags: jsf, testing

I have this code for a backing bean:

```
@PostConstruct
 public void refreshData()
 {
  rows  = (int) dd.getRows();
  pages = dd.getPages();
  getRender();
 }

// action
 public void getCount(String sql, Object... values)
  throws Exception
 {
  dd.getCount(sql, values);
  rows  = (int) dd.getRows();
  pages = dd.getPages();
 }

 // getter methods
    public boolean getRender() {
        System.out.println("pages: "+pages);
     boolean rendered = pages > 0? true: false;
     return rendered;
    } 

 public int getRows() {
  return rows;
 }
    public int getPages() {       
     return pages;
    }
```

Does the **refreshData()** method with the **@PostConstruct** directive get executed after or before all the getter methods? I ask this because I notice the **getRender()** method always return zero even though the **getPages()** returns a number like 10 for example.

Answer (score 11):

I have no idea what you mean with "before all the getter methods". At least the `@PostConstruct` is called immediately after the construction of the bean **and** the setting of all managed properties (the bean properties which are definied in `faces-config.xml`).

Thus roughly:

1. Bean is constructed.
2. Managed properties are set.
3. @PostConstruct is called.
4. Bean is brought in JSF lifecycle.

Your problem is likely that the value is been overriden by something else. Just run the debugger or have your code reviewed by an expert.

Answer (score 8):

The [JSF 1.2 spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr252/index2.html) says specifically (Page 11, Item 119 preface):

> Methods on managed beans declared to be in request, session, or application
>   scope, annotated with @PostConstruct, must be called by the JSF implementation after
>   resource injection is performed (if any) but before the bean is placed into scope.

(More details in the spec.)