# At which phase is managed bean constructed and which constructor is used

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, construction

Consider example of JSF based web-app `hello1` from official tutorial with addition constructor in managed bean. The follow `index.xhtml` facelet

```
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelets Hello Greeting</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:graphicImage url="#{resource['images:duke.waving.gif']}" 
                            alt="Duke waving his hand"/>
            <h2>Hello hui, my name is Duke. What's yours?</h2>
            <h:inputText id="username"
                         title="My name is: "
                         value="#{hello.name}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Error: A name is required."
                         maxlength="25" />
            <p></p>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response">
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <div class="messagecolor">
            <h:messages showSummary="true" 
                        showDetail="false"
                        errorStyle="color: #d20005" 
                        infoStyle="color: blue"/>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and modidfied managed bean `Hello.java`

```
package javaeetutorial.hello1;


import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Hello {

    private String name;

    public Hello() {
    }
    public Hello(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String user_name) {
        this.name = user_name;
    }
}
```

There are **two** public constructors. Let we deploy this app on server and sent initial request, type the name in `inputText` and click `submit`. There is postback request after `submit` click. Hence, as written in tutroial, we have the following subphase of execute phase:

1. The application view is built or restored.
2. The request parameter values are applied.
3. Conversions and validations are performed for component values.
4. Managed beans are updated with component values.
5. Application logic is invoked.

At what phase instance of managed bean will be created?

What constructor will be invoked for this instance creation and why? I dont understand how it can be observe from the `index.xhtml` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *At what phase instance of managed bean will be created?*

No one specifically. It's constructed for the first time when an arbitrary EL expression needs to reference the managed bean for the first time while the bean instance isn't present in its scope. This is not dependent on any particular faces event. This can be during restore view phase (the first phase), but this can also be as good during render response phase (the last phase), or any other phase in between.

This all depends on how and where the bean is referenced in EL context via `#{bean.xxx}` in the view (or programmatically in the model). You should generally not worry about this. JSF (specifically EL) will at least not construct it sooner than necessary in order to properly build or process or render the view.

---

> *What constructor will be invoked for this instance creation and why?*

The default constructor, of course. Because the Javabeans specification says so. All other constructors are never used by JSF/CDI managed bean facility.

Even then, you should not be worrying about constructors. You'd better perform initialization in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method instead of in a constructor. Namely, when the bean is managed by a bean management framework which uses proxies, such as CDI, the default constructor may be called more often than desired.

---

> *I don't understand how it can be observe from the index.xhtml code.*

Just put a breakpoint in constructor, `@PostConstruct`, or whatever relevant getter/setter method and run the project in debug mode. Once the breakpoint hits, examine the call stack. The involved classes and methods have generally rather self-documenting names. Here's an example how the call stack can look like when you're using `@Named`:

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-8088-exec-6] (Suspended (entry into method <init> in TestBean)) 
    owns: LocalCache$StrongEntry  (id=503)  
    owns: SocketWrapper  (id=504)   
    TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>() line: not available [local variables unavailable]   
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 57    
    DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 45    
    Constructor.newInstance(Object...) line: 526    
    Class.newInstance() line: 374   
    NewInstanceAction.run() line: 33    
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
    ClientProxyFactory(ProxyFactory).create(BeanInstance) line: 271 
    ClientProxyFactory.create(BeanInstance) line: 111   
    ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(Bean<T>, Set<Type>) line: 181 
    ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(Bean<T>) line: 171    
    ClientProxyProvider.access$100(ClientProxyProvider, Bean) line: 45  
    ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(Bean<Object>) line: 56   
    ClientProxyProvider$CreateClientProxy.load(Object) line: 52 
    LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(K, CacheLoader<? super K,V>) line: 3589 
    LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(K, int, LoadingValueReference<K,V>, CacheLoader<? super K,V>) line: 2374    
    LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(K, int, CacheLoader<? super K,V>) line: 2337 
    LocalCache$Segment.get(K, int, CacheLoader<? super K,V>) line: 2252 
    LocalCache.get(K, CacheLoader<? super K,V>) line: 3990  
    LocalCache.getOrLoad(K) line: 3994  
    LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(K) line: 4878  
    LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCache<K,V>, K) line: 52  
    LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCache<K,V>, Object) line: 80 
    ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(Bean<T>) line: 187   
    WeldELResolver(AbstractWeldELResolver).lookup(BeanManagerImpl, ELContext, String) line: 110 
    WeldELResolver(AbstractWeldELResolver).getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 91 
    WeldApplication$LazyBeanManagerIntegrationELResolver(ForwardingELResolver).getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 49 
    CompositeELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 67    
    DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(int, ELResolver[], ELContext, Object, Object) line: 176  
    DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 203  
    AstIdentifier.getValue(EvaluationContext) line: 72  
    ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ELContext) line: 185   
    WeldValueExpression.getValue(ELContext) line: 50    
    ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ResponseWriter, ELContext) line: 227    
    ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ResponseWriter, ELContext) line: 150   
    TextInstruction.write(FacesContext) line: 85    
    UIInstructions.encodeBegin(FacesContext) line: 82   
    UIInstructions(UILeaf).encodeAll(FacesContext) line: 207    
    HtmlBody(UIComponent).encodeAll(FacesContext) line: 1899    
    UIViewRoot(UIComponent).encodeAll(FacesContext) line: 1899  
    FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FacesContext, UIViewRoot) line: 451  
    MultiViewHandler.renderView(FacesContext, UIViewRoot) line: 131 
    ConversationAwareViewHandler(ViewHandlerWrapper).renderView(FacesContext, UIViewRoot) line: 337 
    RenderResponsePhase.execute(FacesContext) line: 120 
    RenderResponsePhase(Phase).doPhase(FacesContext, Lifecycle, ListIterator<PhaseListener>) line: 101  
    LifecycleImpl.render(FacesContext) line: 219    
    FacesServlet.service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 647 
    ...
```

Start at the bottom (I've stripped all lines after `FacesServlet.service` as those are generally irrelevant) and read from bottom to top. The `RenderResponsePhase.execute` tells that it's executed during render response phase. The `TextInstruction.write` tells that it occurred during writing the outcome of EL in template text like so `<p>#{bean.something}</p>`. The remainder is just how the CDI implementation Weld is finding and instantiating the proxy and how it is in turn instantiating the actual bean reference.

If it happened during a different phase, you'd instead of `RenderResponsePhase.execute` have seen for example `UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute` and so on.

Comment: you said "this can also be as good during render response phase " I think that mean the bean will be instantiated after `PreRenderViewEvent` is that possible? also, you said her that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804799/4170582 which I think is the opposite of that, could you help me to understand that as I'm pretty sure I missed something

Comment: @Tarik: What part specifically didn't you understand? The answer says *"It's constructed for the first time when an arbitrary EL expression needs to reference the managed bean for the first time while the bean instance isn't present in its scope"*. So this is not phase specific. It can happen during restore view. But it can also happen during render response. And all other phases in between. Just put a debug breakpoint in e.g. `@PostConstruct` and explore the stack if you really want to know the "when".

Comment: Ok, So when that happens in Render phase, that could happen before the PreRenderViewEvent ? I think we have no inssurance regarding that? I got those questions after marked this as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813242/which-executes-first-postconstruct-method-or-a-prerenderview but I think I did a mistake and I can't unflag it

Comment: @Tarik: That question duplicates the current. As answered, the first-time bean construction is not dependent on any specific faces event.